# How to Change Image on the basis of browser detection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I am facing one issue in my HTML page actually I need to implement the below-

1. I need to change my image on the basis of Browser change .So, when I am browsing with Chrome it should load Image1 or if I am browsing with IE then load Image2. Please find the below code which I am using but it is not working for me

   ```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>

    <head>

   <meta charset="utf-8" />

   <title></title>

   <script language="javascript">

   function browsercheck() {
       var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
       return (userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > 0 || !!userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./));
   }

   function displayImage() {
       debugger;

       var browser = browsercheck() ? 'IE' : 'Chrome';
       if (browser == "IE") {
           document.getElementById("image").setAttribute("src", "Image1.jpg");
       }
       else if (browser == "Chrome") {
           document.getElementById("image").setAttribute("src", "Image2.jpg");
       }

   }
   </script>
   </head>
     <body">
   <img id="image" this.src="displayImage()"  alt="can't display picture" />
   </body>
   ```

Comment: Your script is before the `<body>`. That means, that at the time of execution of your `displayImage()` function, your `<body>` and other elements in it, including images, are nonexistent. Thus the images referenced by Id are not found/replaced. Move your script before the closing `</body>` tag to work

Comment: @LudovitMydla Actually, we don't know *when* `displayImage()` is called (which makes it impossible to answer this with certainty, though there's a good chance you're right).

Comment: @PaulRoub You're right. So OP... can you post a full example of your code please?

Comment: Ludovit Paul Hi I have just edited my code I am calling my method on image src attribute but still it is not working for me

Comment: Are you sure you really need to do whatever it is you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

It's simpler to maintain if you distribute responsibilities between CSS and JavaScript. Let each do what it's meant to.

```
<script>
    var browser = browsercheck() ? 'ie' : 'chrome';
    document.body.className += ' ' + browser; // vanilla JS
    // $('body').addClass(browser);           // jQuery version
</script>

<style>
    .image {
        background-image: url("regular.jpg");
    }

    .chrome .image {
        background-image: url("chrome_specific.jpg");
    }    

    .ie .image {
        background-image: url("ie_specific.jpg");
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This JSFiddle shows example of Browser Detection https://jsfiddle.net/311aLtkz/

I think script did not work for you, because you had a function, and you did not use that function on page. Edited code should work when page in opened

```
function browsercheck() {
    var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
    return (userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > 0 || !!userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./));
}

var browser = browsercheck() ? 'IE' : 'Chrome';
    if (browser == "IE") {
        document.getElementById("image").setAttribute("src", "Image1.jpg");
        console.log("IE");
    }
    else if (browser == "Chrome") {
        document.getElementById("image").setAttribute("src", "Image2.jpg");
        console.log("Chrome");
    }
```

Comment: Hi I have just edited my code I am calling my method on image src attribute but still it is not working for me